# Summer hour in angular-moment-picker

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-moment

Hi I encounter an issue concerning angular-moment-picker for time picker,  whenever i try to pickthe time, in my laptop the system time has an extra hour instead of `00:00` i have `01:00` but the time picker still gives me `00:00` as result.
Thank you for answering my issue.

Comment: Give us fiddle example.

Comment: @hurricane I hope it's clear whenever i change my system time, angular moment picker, I pick 17:00 and time picker while debugging shows 16:00.

Comment: And what is your timezone? If it's +1/-1 hour, then surely that's a remarkable coincidence...

Comment: @ippi Thank you for this answer, the timezone I have chosen Central Africa

Comment: Central Africa +1

Comment: @ippi I want to display the same time setted on my local

Comment: Show the code you have for displaying time.